# Why vue computed function could destructuring assignment the parameter when didn't have argument?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

```js
new Vue({
      el: "#app",
       data: {
         value: "text",
       },
       computed:{
        all: function({value}){
          return value
        }
       }
      });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  {{ value }}
  <br>
  {{ all }}
</div>
```

Didn't see this usage on Vue document.

but I saw this on my project, why this usage could work?

```
   computed:{
    all: function({value}){
      return value
    }
   }
```

First i think when function didn't get argument, would take "this" be the argument. see below.

but is wrong. so why computed didn't get argument, Destructuring assignment the parameter still work?

```js
var value = "couldn't fly";
function ref ({value}){
  console.log(value)
}

ref({
  value : "could fly"
})

// didn't get window
try{
  ref();
}catch(e){
  console.log('error')
}


// ===================================================


class cal {
  constructor(){
    value : "couldn't walk"
  }
  ref({value}){
    console.log(value, "in Class")
  }
}

let calRef = new cal;
calRef.ref({
  value: "could walk"
})


// didn't get the constructor value
try{
  calRef.ref()
}catch(e){
  console.log('error')
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is documented in the [API guide](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#computed)...

> Note that if you use an arrow function with a computed property, `this` won’t be the component’s instance, but you can still access the instance as the function’s **first argument**

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    value: "text",
  },
  computed: {
    all (vm) {
      console.log('from all, is vm equal to this?', vm === this)
      return vm.value
    },
    arrowed: vm => vm.value.toUpperCase(),
    destructuredArrow: ({ value }) => value.toUpperCase()
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <pre>value = {{ value }}</pre>
  <pre>all = {{ all }}</pre>
  <pre>arrowed = {{ arrowed }}</pre>
  <pre>destructuredArrow = {{ destructuredArrow }}</pre>
</div>
```

---

Just found a handy extra hint... this same pattern applies to a component's `data` function

```js
export default {
  props: { someProp: String },
  data: vm => ({ localCopy: vm.someProp })
}
```

Comment: so... argument is exist, haha i'm such blind.